# Can pthread_cond_wait() always win the competition in locking a mutex?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

This question is regarding the pthread tutorial in [llnl](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). 
Say there are three threads.

**Thread 1:**

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)
do_something...
if condition
    pthread_cond_signal(&con)
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)
repeat
```

**Thread 2:**

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)
do_something...
if condition
    pthread_cond_signal(&con)
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)
repeat
```

**Thread 3:**

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)
while(condition not holds)
    pthread_cond_wait(&con)
    do_something...
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)
```

Assume that *Thread1* checks that condition is satisfied and then sends signal to wake up *Thread3*. Finally it unlocks the mutex. But at the same time, *Thread 2* is trying to lock the mutex.

My question is: is there any guarantee that *Thread3* will always win in the competition?

If not then after *Thread2* do_something..., the condition variable may be changed, then when *Thread3* gets to lock the mutex, the condition variable is different from what it expects.

Comment: There is no such guarantee. If at all it happened 10 out of 10 times, it's still purely out of luck.

Comment: There is no such guarantee. This is *precisely why* you need the while loop around `pthread_cond_wait`! And you shouldn't have `do_something...` inside that while loop for the same reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*My question is: is there any guarantee that Tread3 will always win in the competition?*

No such guarantees. From [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> The pthread_cond_signal() function shall unblock at least one of the
>   threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable cond (if
>   any threads are blocked on cond).
>
> **If more than one thread is blocked on a condition variable, the
>   scheduling policy shall determine the order in which threads are
>   unblocked.** When each thread unblocked as a result of a
>   pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() returns from its
>   call to pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait(), the thread
>   shall own the mutex with which it called pthread_cond_wait() or
>   pthread_cond_timedwait(). **The thread(s) that are unblocked shall
>   contend for the mutex according to the scheduling policy (if
>   applicable), and as if each had called pthread_mutex_lock().**

(Emphasis mine).

*If not then after Tread2 do_something..., the condition variable may be changed, then when Tread3 gets to lock the mutex, the condition variable is different from what it expects.*

If the *order of execution* of threads matter then you probably need to rewrite your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee.  Returning from `pthread_cond_wait()` should be treated as implying that the condition *might* have changed, not that it definitely has - so you need to re-check the condition, and may need to wait again.  This is exactly why `pthread_cond_wait()` should be called within a loop that checks the condition.